# Can REST be followed by STOR?

Tags: ftp, ftp-server

I'm trying to create a simple FTP server, and I'm not sure how to implement REST correctly.

The [documentation](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) says that the REST command affects the command immediately following it, but it doesn't say which commands can follow REST.

I assume it's used mostly for RETR, so a file download can be resumed, but I'm not sure about STOR, since APPE already does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) - `REST` can be followed by `APPE`, `STOR`, or `RETR`.