# Does uploading a file via an API require FTP access to the server?

Tags: rest, ftp, multipartform-data

I am a technical writer (not a programmer) who is documenting a REST API with almost no internal documentation and limited access to the devs who created the API.

There is a resource in the API that allows you to upload a file to the server and then returns an ID (to reference the file in future requests). Even though the request is returning an ID (and a 200 http status code), the file is not actually being added to the database.

When the UI calls this request everything works great, but I cannot replicate a successful request in Postman.

Is this possibly an issue related to FTP access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST API does not need FTP access. REST has nothing to do with FTP whatsoever.

Quite on the contrary. REST is a stateless protocol (It runs over HTTP).

While FTP is stateful protocol.

---

*A similar (while not the same) question: [Can REST be implemented over FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35534812/850848)*

Comment: What I understand from your answer is that requiring FTP would violate REST standards. But it I would think it is still possible that this could be required?

Comment: @Ashira In case it's not clear from my answer: REST has nothing to do with FTP whatsoever.

Comment: I am asking whether it would be theoretically possible for an API request to require FTP access, even if requiring FTP would make the request unRESTful.

Comment: As theoretically as it may theoretically require you to wear a red hat while issuing the REST request.